# How can I create same number of input fields and fetch the data from available list items using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have three list items (those are dynamically created and can be more or less also) whose have checkboxes and labels.

Based on number of items (`<li>`'s), I want to create input fields with index numbers ('`Item 1, Item 2, etc...`') dynamically.

Currently, I am manually appending number of divs based on list items. These list can be vary based on condition.

How can I achive this dynamically instead of using nth-child (manualy)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/z91tmwxb/19/)

[image]

```js
$(document).on('click', '#getCheckboxesContent', function(){
  var count = $('.checkboxes ul li').length;
  var value1 = $('.checkboxes ul li:nth-child(1) label .lbl').text();
  var value2 = $('.checkboxes ul li:nth-child(2) label .lbl').text();
  var value3 = $('.checkboxes ul li:nth-child(3) label .lbl').text();
  $('.checkboxes-content').html('');
  $('.checkboxes-content').append('Total checkboxes : ' + count);
  $('.checkboxes-content').append('<div class="item">Item 1 : <input type="text" value="'+value1+'" /></div>');
  $('.checkboxes-content').append('<div class="item">Item 2 : <input type="text" value="'+value2+'" /></div>');
  $('.checkboxes-content').append('<div class="item">Item 3 : <input type="text" value="'+value3+'" /></div>');
})
```

```css
body{font-family:verdana;font-size:14px;}
.checkboxes{padding:20px;}
ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
li{margin-top:5px;}
label .lbl{margin-left:5px;}
.item{margin-top:10px;background:#efefef;padding:10px;}
h2{font-weight:bold;margin:0;padding:0;font-size:16px;}
.checkboxes-content{margin:15px;}
#getCheckboxesContent{margin-left:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-sm" name="checkbox"><span class="lbl">Checkbox 1</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-sm" name="checkbox"><span class="lbl">Checkbox 2</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-sm" name="checkbox"><span class="lbl">Checkbox 3</span></label></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" id="getCheckboxesContent">Get content</a>

<div class="checkboxes-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this dynamically would be to select all the relevant `:checkbox` elements in the DOM and then use `map()` to build a `div` for each of them in an array. The HTML can then be appended to the DOM in the target location. Try this:

```js
let $checkboxContent = $('.checkboxes-content');

$(document).on('click', '#getCheckboxesContent', function() {
  let html = $('.checkboxes :checkbox').map((i, el) => `<div class="item">Item ${i + 1}: <input type="text" value="${el.nextElementSibling.textContent}" /></div>`).get();
  $checkboxContent.append(html);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.checkboxes {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

label .lbl {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.checkboxes-content {
  margin: 15px;
}

#getCheckboxesContent {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-sm" name="checkbox"><span class="lbl">Checkbox 1</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-sm" name="checkbox"><span class="lbl">Checkbox 2</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-sm" name="checkbox"><span class="lbl">Checkbox 3</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-sm" name="checkbox"><span class="lbl">Checkbox 4</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-sm" name="checkbox"><span class="lbl">Checkbox 5</span></label></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" id="getCheckboxesContent">Get content</a>

<div class="checkboxes-content"></div>
```

If the number of divs should *always* equal the number of checkboxes then you should consider changing `append()` to `html()`, so that successive clicks of the button don't add an infinite number of elements.

Comment: **@Rory McCrossan**, again you have saved my day :)... This is what exactly I want... Thanks for the **TIP**... **I am Accepting and Upvoting** your awesome answer :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Sorry, missed... I want to fetch the Textfield value from **<span class="lbl">**, not as index numbers as 1,2,3... can you please alter the code.... sorry for the confusion...

Comment: Sure, change `i + 1` to `el.nextElementSibling.textContent` in that case. I've updated the answer to give you an example

Comment: Awesome... working like a charm :) Thanks again